# Tensorflow: GPU suddenly explode during training

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

During training, for some of the data (for example, first 25 samples), my GPU occupancy rate has not changed, but for a certain sample, my GPU **suddenly** exploded.

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution: Linux Ubuntu 16.04):
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): pip
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.13.1
- Python version: 3.7
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 10.0
- GPU model and memory: Nvidia 2080 8G

When I train the network,  for the first 25 samples of training, usage of memory and GPU were unchanged: 
[image]
[image]

But when it comes to 46-th sample, I got:
[image]
And the usage of GPU and memory added:
[image]
[image]

And when to comes to 96-th sample.

```
Limit:                  7012814029
InUse:                  4755516416
MaxInUse:               5347089664
NumAllocs:                  624595
MaxAllocSize:           2055250688

2020-06-12 22:52:55.958865: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] ****************__********************************************************************___***********
2020-06-12 22:52:55.959733: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at aggregate_ops.cc:70 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[129675,512] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frank/anaconda3/envs/smpl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py", line 553, in _aggregate_grads
    return gen_math_ops.add_n(gradients)
  File "/home/frank/anaconda3/envs/smpl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 428, in add_n
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[129675,512] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:AddN]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/reconstruction_NN/reconstruction_test.py", line 634, in <module>
    train_model()
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/reconstruction_NN/reconstruction_test.py", line 538, in train_model
    lo = m.train(train_dat, gt_dat, loss_dict)
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/reconstruction_NN/reconstruction_NN.py", line 498, in train
    grad = gtape.gradient(loss_, self.trainable_variables)
  File "/home/frank/anaconda3/envs/smpl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py", line 946, in gradient
    unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
  File "/home/frank/anaconda3/envs/smpl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/imperative_grad.py", line 72, in imperative_grad
    compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))
  File "/home/frank/anaconda3/envs/smpl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py", line 126, in _gradient_function
    mock_op = _MockOp(attr_tuple, inputs, outputs, op_name)
SystemError: <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.backprop._MockOp'> returned a result with an error set

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It seems like something wrong with
[image]

(It is almost impossible to show my large proj.) I show how I load data and how I train the NN:
(Load training pairs one by one.)

```
for ep in range(50):
    start = time.time()
    loss = None
    for i in range(begin_index,begin_index+feeding_size): #range(1): #range(len(gen)):
        st = time.time()
        # if(i == 46):
        #     continue
        print('processing: epoch', ep, '  ',i)
        train_dat = pkl.load(open('/media/frank/Elements1/data/Train_data/Training_pairs/shuffled_input_data/shuffle_input_dat270_510_%d.pkl' %i, "rb"),
                             encoding="latin1")  # added this encoding stuff for Python3
        gt_dat = pkl.load(open('/media/frank/Elements1/data/Train_data/Training_pairs/shuffled_gt_data/shuffle_gt_dat270_510_%d.pkl' %i, "rb"),
                             encoding="latin1")  # added this encoding stuff for Python3
        print("here")
        for i in range(0, 10):
            gt_dat['trans_' + str(i)] = np.zeros((1, 3))
        lo = m.train(train_dat, gt_dat, loss_dict)
        if loss is None:
            loss = lo
        else:
            for k in lo:
                loss[k] += lo[k]
        print(loss)
        print(time.time() - st)
    for k in loss:
        loss[k]/=float(feeding_size)
```

(train.)

```
def train(self, inp_dict, gt_dict, loss_dict, specific_opt=None):
    # tf.print("size of NUM: ", NUM)
    images = [inp_dict['image_{}'.format(i)].astype('float32') for i in range(NUM)]
    J_2d = [inp_dict['J_2d_{}'.format(i)].astype('float32') for i in range(NUM)]

    with tf.GradientTape() as gtape:
        out_dict = self.call([images, J_2d])
        loss = self.loss_model(gt_dict, out_dict, wt_dict=loss_dict)
        loss_ = 0
        for k in loss:
            loss_ += loss[k]  # get the sum of all loss.

        grad = gtape.gradient(loss_, self.trainable_variables)

        if specific_opt is not None:  # optimize specific loss
            opt_var, opt_grad = [], []
            print("we are here!")
            for x, g in zip(self.trainable_variables, grad):
                if x.name in specific_opt:
                    opt_var.append(x)
                    opt_grad.append(g)
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(
                zip(opt_grad, opt_var))
        else:
            print("we are here!")
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(
                zip(grad, self.trainable_variables))
    for k in loss:
        # print(type(loss[k]))
        loss[k] = loss[k].numpy()  # get the sum of all loss.
        # print(type(loss[k]))
    # print(type(loss))
    # input("ok")
    return loss
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: As detailed on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**.". Screenshots of code is not enough to satisfy the "in the question itself" bit, and therefore are off-topic. Please correct it to include the code.

Comment: @MSalters It is almost impossible to show my large proj. I show how I load data and how I train the NN.